# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OCMArg"

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ocmock

I added OCMock version 3.9.1 to my project.
The LibPods-* file seems to be linked (checked Target->Build Phases->Link Binary). But during runtime the OCMock framework isn't getting recognized.
I also tried to manually link the libOCMock.a file, but no luck.
Been stuck with this issue for a while.
The OCMock.a file is also present in the build directory of Derived Data, how do I link them correctly.
Always let the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OCMArg",
```

EDIT :
I found my problem. Inside the intermediate build folder ../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulate, OCMcck generates a folder and libOCMock.a sits inside it. My project while building has no access to that lib. If I manually move the file libOCMock.a one level down to the folder Debug-iphonesimulate, everything works as expected. Now how do I change my xcode settings to make my project look into folders recursively in the Build directory?

Answer (score 0):

Without some code, there isn’t much we can do to help. OCMock has been around for the past 10yrs and it supports x86_64 architecture.
I suspect the issue might lie in pods. Try to clean install pods in your project and delete the derived data and build again.

For a temporary work around you can try to remove x86_64 from your Valid Architectures under Build settings in Xcode. Then you can try to run the project on an iPhone.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I found my problem. Inside the intermediate build folder ../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulate, OCMcck generates a folder and libOCMock.a sits inside it. My project while building has no access to that lib. If I manually move the file libOCMock.a one level down to the folder Debug-iphonesimulate, everything works as expected. Now how do I change my xcode settings to make my project look into folders recursively in the Build directory?

Comment: Try adding $(inherited) in Framework search path, under build settings.

Comment: Tried it, no luck :(

Comment: The cause for these kind of errors (Undefined symbols for architecture ....) will vary from machine to machine. Ultimately its you who has to find out the solution.

Just remember that Xcode is unable to find the required Class/method that you are referencing in your project. There might be many reasons why this might be the case, like forgot to add the framework to bundle, failing to check the target membership, failing to include the framework in Link Binary With Libraries under Build Phases, etc. 

Hope this helps and Good Luck!!!